# JSON Parsing Date with DateTimeParseException/JsonbException from ClientBuilder/WebTarget program

Tags: java, json, datetimeparseexception

I having problem parsing a date for `JSON`, when my program consumes a `POST` Services that contains a `Body`, Instead of `REST` client program `Postman` works perfectly.

Using Postman with URL **http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customers/createPurchaser**

[image]

With the Header
[image]

The output from console of my Program client is:

**java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '653038060000' could not be parsed at index 0**

The code of my program client (`ConsumingServices` class) is:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class ConsumingServices {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setFirstName("John");
        customer.setLastName("Mason");
        customer.setEmail("john.mason@mail.com");
        customer.setDateOfBirth(new Date());
        customer.setStatus(CustomerStatus.ACTIVE);
        
        ClientBuilder clientBuilder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
        clientBuilder.connectTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        clientBuilder.readTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Client client = clientBuilder.build();

        WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customers");

        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.path("createPurchaser")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                ;

        Response response = invocationBuilder
                .header("Authorization", "1234")
                .post(Entity.entity(customer, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        System.out.println("response.getStatus():" + response.getStatus());
        if (response.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
            Purchaser purchaser = response.readEntity(Purchaser.class);
            System.out.println("purchaser:".concat(purchaser.toString()));
        } else {
            if (MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE.equals(response.getMediaType())) {
                String message = response.readEntity(String.class);
                System.out.println("message:" + message);
            } else if (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.equals(response.getMediaType())) {
                ApiError apiError = response.readEntity(ApiError.class);
                System.out.println("apiError:".concat(apiError.toString()));
            } else {
                System.out.println("response.getMediaType():" + response.getMediaType());
                String content = response.readEntity(String.class);
                System.out.println("message:" + content);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ acme-customers-client ---
response.getStatus():500

response.getMediaType():text/html
message:<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Payara Server  5.2020.3 #badassfish - Error report</title><style type="text/css"><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error</h1><hr/><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b>Internal Server Error</p><p><b>description</b>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to deserialize property &#39;dateOfBirth&#39; because of: Error parsing class java.util.Date from value: 1599180453470. Check your @JsonbDateFormat has all time units for class java.util.Date type, or consider using org.eclipse.yasson.YassonConfig#ZERO_TIME_PARSE_DEFAULTING.</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Error parsing class java.util.Date from value: 1599180453470. Check your @JsonbDateFormat has all time units for class java.util.Date type, or consider using org.eclipse.yasson.YassonConfig#ZERO_TIME_PARSE_DEFAULTING.</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text &#39;1599180453470&#39; could not be parsed at index 0</pre></p><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the Payara Server  5.2020.3 #badassfish logs.</u></p><hr/><h3>Payara Server  5.2020.3 #badassfish</h3></body></html>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  5.574 s
Finished at: 2020-09-03T19:47:36-05:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The Styled Output.

```
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.
root cause

javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.
root cause

javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to deserialize property 'dateOfBirth' because of: Error parsing class java.util.Date from value: 653038060000. Check your @JsonbDateFormat has all time units for class java.util.Date type, or consider using org.eclipse.yasson.YassonConfig#ZERO_TIME_PARSE_DEFAULTING.
root cause

javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Error parsing class java.util.Date from value: 653038060000. Check your @JsonbDateFormat has all time units for class java.util.Date type, or consider using org.eclipse.yasson.YassonConfig#ZERO_TIME_PARSE_DEFAULTING.
root cause

java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '653038060000' could not be parsed at index 0
```

The `Customer` class (the all code is in this question [javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException, could not find writer for content-type application/json type, in Payara Server 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63727978/811293))

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer extends BaseType implements Serializable {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private CustomerStatus status;
    private String email;
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public CustomerStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(CustomerStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

The `pom.xml` dependencies of my program client are:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>acme-customers-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.inject/jersey-hk2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**How can I solve this problem in my client(using `ClientBuilder/WebTarget)` program, if using a REST client program works fine??**

Comment: Looks like your time is in millis - Have you tried annotating dateOfBirth field  with @JsonbDateFormat(JsonbDateFormat.TIME_IN_MILLIS) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely is in parsing your `Customer` class instance to JSON in your client program. Note that in Postman you already provide proper JSON (the one that you expect that your `Customer` class instance would be parsed to), but in your client program you expect your Http client code to parse your `Customer` class instance to JSON in this piece of code:

```
Response response = invocationBuilder
            .header("Authorization", "1234")
            .post(Entity.entity(customer, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

However, the date gets parsed to '653038060000' just as your error message tells you. So, I suggest  first to test if my assumption is correct, to try to send your JSON text instead of `Customer` class instance from your client program. If my assumption is correct, this would work. If so, then you need to make sure that whichever way you parse your `Customer` class instance to JSON is correct. Either do it yourself using some JSON library (I suggest Jackson Json, [GitHub Jackson home](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). Here are Maven artifacts:

```
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

) or get your Http client `Invocation.Builder` to parse it correctly. To do so you might want to add in your Customer class the following annotation:

```
   @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
   private Date dateOfBirth;
```

You might need to add the same Jackson Maven artifacts to your code. For detailed answer, see this question: [Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization)
Also, if you are using Java 8 or above I **VERY STRONGLY** recommend not to use the outdated `Date` class (no pun intended) but switch to `java.time` package and use instead [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class or other available classes such as `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` or others.
Finally, if you like you may try another 3d party Http Client from MgntUtils library. Here is its JavaDoc: [HttpClient](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html). The library itself you can find here as [Maven Artifacts](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) and here on the [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc). This library does not parse classes to JSON though but can send text as the request body. (Disclaimer: this library is written by me).

Comment: previously, I checked https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat and `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")` due to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53342519/811293

Comment: Well, did you test sending JSON string instead of your class? And seriously, switch to LocalDate instead of Date